# Storage life for goose fat

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, fat

When I roast a goose, I decant the fat, strain and freeze it. I typically get a pint or more. This seems to work well, I can chip off suitably-sized pieces from the frozen block and use them as necessary. But is this the best way to store it, and if so, how long can I leave it for in the freezer before it's no longer safe to use?

Comment: Awesome idea - in the freezer! Never thought of that, I just keep it in a jar until it goes rancid :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't go unsafe if it's refrigerated or frozen, but it might pick up off flavors or turn rancid eventually. You can probably use it for 6 months if it's well-sealed and not exposed to air.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a frozen pot for a year an it was still good. I threw it out after that just in case!